# wordpress add an image to a taxonomy actor

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I was wanting to add a image to my custom taxonomy actor, but when I look in the edit actor options it only shows the options name, slug & description.
I need to add an option in the functions.php for the above mentioned problem.

```
////////////////////////////////////
//         TAXONOMY ACTORS        //
////////////////////////////////////

register_taxonomy(
    'actor',
    array( 'movies' ),
    array(
        'labels'            => array(
        'name'              => __( 'Actors' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Actor' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Actors' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Actors' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Actor' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Actor:' ),
        'view_item'         => __( 'View Actor' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Actor' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Actor' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Actor' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Actor Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Actor' ),
        ),
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'actor' ),
    )
);
```

I have tried to find out how I would achieve this without asking here, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPD. My answer is about custom post types, not custom taxonomies. As @betatester07 noted in the comments, the [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) function does not have the `supports` parameter that [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) has. But since the answer is accepted, I can't delete it.

Here on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/158020/93163) you can find solutions using the Term Meta or WP plugins.

---

Try to add the `supports` parameter:

```
'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' ),
```

For example:

```
...
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'actor' ),
        'supports'          => array( 'thumbnail' ),
    )
);
```

For details, see "**Step 5: Function Implementation**" in [this guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes--wp-27645):

> `'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' )` determines the features of the custom post type which is to be displayed.

Comment: I have added the afore mentioned code to my functions.php now all I need is an option to add the image file to the edit actor page.

Comment: I have successfully added the support into my functions.php. But how do I view the image on my site as it has definitely saved it to a certain taxonomy actor. tvm

Comment: You can ask a new question about the next stage of your task. The more detailed you describe what you have already done and the difficulties that you have encountered, the sooner someone from the community will offer you a suitable solution.

Comment: Please explain the reason of the downvoting. It helps me and everyone else to correct mistakes.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky it is probably because the original question is about **custom taxonomy** and you are referring to **custom posts**. Not all parameters are supported by both.

Comment: @betatester07 Thanks for your explanation. Looks like I have misunderstood the problem and my answer is marked as solution unfairly. Alas I can't delete accepted answer

Comment: @GlebKemarsky AFAIK, you can still edit your answer to add a notice that it works only for custom posts