# View picture added to a custom taxonomy actor

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

This is a follow-up question of :

[wordpress add an image to a taxonomy actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375024/wordpress-add-an-image-to-a-taxonomy-actor)

I have successfully added the support into my functions.php. But how do I view the image on my site as it has definitely saved it to a certain taxonomy actor.

https://www.screencast.com/t/u6p5xmiDXgz4

https://www.screencast.com/t/ZmZ6b7cwRm

But as of present I have been unable to work out how to view the attached picture to my website.

```
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' ); ?>
    <?php print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check table 'prefix_termmeta', you can found term_meta value with given 'term_id'.
Or let me know what function/Plugin have been used to add images to Custom Taxonomy?

Comment: WP Term Images is the plugin I am using, and I have also added image support within my functions.php.  in register taxonomy actor/movies 'supports'   => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),

Comment: Please check Plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-images/
http://prntscr.com/i7hui8

Comment: typed exactly as was in the pic, no errors and no picture :( thanks for trying